# How to show $f$ is injective or surjective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Define a function $f : P(\{0, 1\}) × P(\{1, 2\}) \to \{0, 1, 2\}$ by $f((D, E)) =| D \cap E |$.

Note that $P$ is the power set.

To determine injectivity: I need to show that distinct elements of the domain ($P(\{0, 1\}) \times P(\{1, 2\}))$ map to distinct elements of the codomain $(\{0, 1, 2\})$.

But in this case, $f$ is not injective right?

Just for an example, let $D = \{(1,0)\}$ and $E = \{(0,1)\}$ and $D_2 =\{(2,1)\}$ and $E_2 = \{(1,2)\}, | D2 \cap E2 |$ is the same as $| D \cap E |$ since both map to $\{2\}$. So that means $f$ is not one to one (injectivity), but many to one?

To show for surjectivity, can I do that same thing by just listing examples? Like I will show that for every element in the codomain $\{0,1,2\}$, there is least one preimage in the domain $(P(\{0, 1\}) \times P(\{1, 2\}))$?

Comment: When writing MathJax use `\{` and `\}` to get $\{$ and $\}$.

Answer (score 0):

You got the right idea for injectivity, but your notation is really bad, and it hurts your arguments. I'm assuming you mean for example that $A$ is the set $\{0,1\}$? Well, then $A=B$ and $A_2=B_2$, since sets are not ordered pairs.

You can modify your argument by considering the sets $\{0,1\}$, $\{1\}$ and $\{1, 2\}$.

For surjectivity, you can show that $2$ will never be hit, since

$|\{0,1\}\cap \{1, 2\}|= |\{1\}|=1$

Comment: Why would 2 never be hit? So f is also not surjective? How would you prove this?

Comment: The reason is stated above. $\{0,1\}$ is the largest set in $P(\{0,1\})$ and $\{1, 2\}$ is the largest set in $P(\{0,1\})$, so $f(\{0,1\}, \{1, 2\}=1$ on those sets is maximal.

Answer (score 0):

Notation first of all:

$A=p(\{0,1\}), B=p(\{1,2\})$

$A=\{\emptyset, \{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}\\
B=\{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$

$|D=A\times B|=16$
And
$A\cap B=\{\emptyset, \{1\}\}$

So the function can not be injective.

It is however surjective.

$\emptyset\in D$ since every cartesian product that contains $\emptyset$ is empty by definition and intersection of $\emptyset$ with any set is empty.

So $0\in R(f)$, where $R$ stands for range.

Also:

The cartesian product of $\{1\}\times \{1\}$ is simply
$<\{1\},\{1\}>=\{\{1\},\{\{1\},\{1\}\}\}$

$=\{\{1\}\}$ so it's intersection with itself has cardinality 1.

Cardinality 2 is easy to prove.

Edit:

On second glance no intersection of subsets of $A$ and subsets of $B$ will give you a set of cardinality 2.
So Jensen is right.

It is not surjective.

Comment: Richard Jensen said in previous answer that it is not surjective?